# Bind Image src to IFormFile asp.net core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am starting to learn Asp.Net core. I have a model class which is saved to the database as follows:

```
public class BlogData
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string BlogTitle { get; set; }
        public string BlogContent { get; set; }
        public DateTime PostedDateTime { get; set; }
        public byte[] ImageData { get; set; }
    }
```

Now I created another class as follows:

```
public class BlogDataWithStringImage : BlogData
    {
        private IFormFile _actualImage;
        public IFormFile ActualImage
        {
            get => _actualImage;
            set
            {
                if (value != null)
                {
                    using var fs1 = value.OpenReadStream();
                    using var ms1 = new MemoryStream();
                    fs1.CopyTo(ms1);
                    ImageData = ms1.ToArray();
                }
                _actualImage = value;
            }
        }
    }
```

My intention is when some value gets bound to the ActualImage property, I want to convert it to byte Array. Problem is, when I keep a breakpoint on the set block of (ActualImage property in BlogDataWithStringImage class) the breakpoint never gets hit even when I choose the image on the View.

```
 @model KGSBlog.Models.BlogDataWithStringImage

@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "Create";
}

<h1>Create</h1>

<h4>BlogData</h4>
<hr />
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-4">
        <form asp-action="Create" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            <div asp-validation-summary="ModelOnly" class="text-danger"></div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BlogTitle" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BlogTitle" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BlogTitle" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="BlogContent" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="BlogContent" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="BlogContent" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label asp-for="PostedDateTime" class="control-label"></label>
                <input asp-for="PostedDateTime" class="form-control" />
                <span asp-validation-for="PostedDateTime" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label asp-for="ActualImage" class="control-label"></label>
                    <div class="custom-file">
                        <input asp-for="ActualImage" class="custom-file-input" id="customFile">
                        <label class="custom-file-label" for="customFile">Choose file</label>@*Choosing an image never sets the ActualImage property*@
                    </div>
                    <span asp-validation-for="ActualImage" class="text-danger"></span>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <input type="submit" value="Create" class="btn btn-primary" />
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
</div>

<div>
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @{await Html.RenderPartialAsync("_ValidationScriptsPartial");}
}
```

Comment: A HTML form needs the `enctype="multipart/form-data"` attribute before any files can be uploaded from it

Comment: My bad let me try. Even then it dosen't hit the set block. I edited my post.

Comment: When using `enctype="multipart/form-data"`,and make sure the name of input is the same with the property you want to binded in action,the file will be binded.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out. I was refering to this post in case if it helps someone, [Image upload asp.net core](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/upload-and-display-image-in-asp-net-core-3-1/)

I added the following script inside the Scripts section as in the above post and it works fine.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".custom-file-input").on("change", function () {
        var fileName = $(this).val().split("\\").pop();
        $(this).siblings(".custom-file-label").addClass("selected").html(fileName);
    });  
</script>
```

Comment: This bit of jquery doesn't solve your model binding problem. Or was simply printing the file name on the screen the real goal all along?

Comment: No I wanted to model bind with the Set Block of the property, so I can convert that Image to byte array and save to the DB. With the script, I have a break point on the set block. When I select an image and 'SUBMIT' the form, the breakpoint is coming fine to the Set Block.

Comment: OK. But this code in your answer wouldn't make that suddenly work, it's unrelated. Something else must have changed as well

Comment: Without the script when I chose a file, I couldn't see the file path in the file picker. But with the script I am able to see the file path in the file picker. And when I clicked submit, the associated controller action method was getting the IFormFile property.

Comment: This code just updates a label with the file name. Label data isn't submitted to the server.